# Why would I not be able to drill through a concrete wall splitting our house/laundry room and garage?

Tags: concrete, walls, garage, screws, drill

I am trying to hang a suspension rail in our laundry room concrete wall. I got the best concrete drill bit but it just won't go through past half an inch. I'm not sure what the issue is or what options do I have?

I am using this drill: https://www.portercable.com/product/pcc601lb/20v-max-12-brushless-cordless-drilldriver-kit?tid=576141 on the drill setting.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Would need to make hundreds of holes before even thinking of breaking the house, unless putting TNT into them.  A plain drill might be okay if you don't hit a stone, but a hammer drill should go though stones.  Get a drill from a rental place to try out.  Can always add one to your toys after.

Comment: There are many similar questions on this site. Short answer: well-cured concrete needs percussion drilling.

Comment: Vtc: linked question explains need for hammer drill

Comment: ... and a suitable drill bit